# Search a JSON Response using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm using a Ruby script to interface with an application API and the results being returned are in a JSON format. For example:

```
{
  "incidents": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "status": "open",
      "key": "abc123"
    }
    {
      "number": 2,
      "status": "open",
      "key": "xyz098"
    }
    {
      "number": 3,
      "status": "closed",
      "key": "lmn456"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking to search each block for a particular "key" value (yzx098 in this example) and return the associated "number" value.

Now, I'm very new to Ruby and I'm not sure if there's already a function to help accomplish this. However, a couple days of scouring the Googles and Ruby resource books hasn't yielded anything that works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for the [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) of the standard library?

Comment: The hashes need commas between them to be valid parsable json.  I tried to edit the Q, but you need to change 6 characters - can't add 2 commas :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First of all, the JSON should be as below: (note the commas)

```
 {
  "incidents": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "status": "open",
      "key": "abc123"
    },
    {
      "number": 2,
      "status": "open",
      "key": "xyz098"
    },
    {
      "number": 3,
      "status": "closed",
      "key": "lmn456"
    }
  ]
}
```

Strore the above json in a variable

```
s =  '{"incidents": [{"number": 1,"status": "open","key": "abc123"},{"number": 2,"status": "open","key": "xyz098"},{"number": 3,"status": "closed","key": "lmn456"}]}'
```

Parse the JSON

```
h = JSON.parse(s)
```

Find the required `number` using `map`

```
h["incidents"].map {|h1| h1['number'] if h1['key']=='xyz098'}.compact.first
```

Or you could also use `find` as below

```
 h["incidents"].find {|h1| h1['key']=='xyz098'}['number']
```

Or  you could also use `select` as below

```
h["incidents"].select {|h1| h1['key']=='xyz098'}.first['number']
```

Comment: don't need `if`.... `select` or `find` throws the selection, whenever block returns `true`. Only `h1['key']=='xyz098'` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Pointed me in the right direction and I was able to get this sorted out. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Do as below

```
# to get numbers from `'key'`.
json_hash["incidents"].map { |h| h['key'][/\d+/].to_i }
```

- `json_hash["incidents"]` - will give you the value of the key `"incidents"`, which is nothing but an array of hash.
- [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) to iterate thorough each hash and collect the value of `'key'`. Then applying [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) to each inner hash of the array, to get the value of `"key"`. Then calling [`str[regexp]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), to get only the number strings like `'098'` from `"xyz098"`, finally applying [`to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) to get the actual integer from it.

If the given hash actually a `json` string, then first parse it using [`JSON::parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) to convert it to a hash.Then do iterate as I said above.

```
require 'json'

json_hash = JSON.parse(json_string)
# to get values from the key `"number"`.
json_hash["incidents"].map { |h| h['number'] } # => [1, 2, 3]
# to search and get all the numbers for a particular key match and take the first
json_hash["incidents"].select { |h| h['key'] == 'abc123' }.first['number'] # => 1
# or to search and get only the first number for a particular key match
json_hash["incidents"].find { |h| h['key'] == 'abc123' }['number'] # => 1
```

Comment: I believe he was asking for the `"number"` field of the hash with key `"xyz098"` This could be done using something like `json_hash["incidents"].select { |h| h['key'] == 'abc123' }.first['number']` which gives you `2`